# trying to multiply values in array based on if they are even or odd

Tags: javascript

Im trying to multiply values in array by 2 if they are even and by 3 if they are odd but my code isnt working at all

here is my current code

```
function modifyArray(nums) {

    nums.forEach(element => {
        if(element % 2 == 0) {
            nums[nums.indexOf(element)] = element * 2;
        } else if (element % 2 != 0) {
            nums[nums.indexOf(element)] = element * 3;
        }
    })

    return nums;

}


modifyArray([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Here is the array it returned [ 9, 8, 3, 4, 15 ]

Comment: Hint: `forEach` can accept the second argument, `index`. You can use it to access the "current" element.

Comment: Change `nums.forEach((element, i)` and `nums[i] = element * 2`. The first item 1 becomes 3 after you multiply. When you do `nums.indexOf(3)` for the third element, it returns index `0` instead of `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code.

```js
function modifyArray(nums) {
  return nums.map(n => { return (n % 2 === 0) ? n * 2 : n * 3 });
}

let result = modifyArray([1,2,3,4,5]);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you explained why their code doesn't work and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can modify your code a little bit. Since forEach() can have 3 arguments where the first argument is elements of the array, second is the index and third is the whole array itself.

```js
function modifyArray(nums) {
  nums.forEach((element, i) => {
    if (element % 2 == 0) {
      nums[i] = element * 2;
    } else {
      nums[i] = element * 3;
    }
  });

  return nums;
}
console.log(modifyArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```